# Parachain Warp sync get stuck at AwaitingPeers status

Tags: parachain, sync

[image]I'm testing warp sync feature with a Parachain node which is available after these commits https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12761.
In my testing, Warp sync for the embedded Relaychain side can smoothly sync the whole state.

Making sure `--sync warp` is set to both para & relay.

```
./collator-bin --sync warp -- --sync warp
```

However, Parachain side often get stuck at `AwaitingPeers` status after taking some time for Downloading states even though it has enough peers seen in logs.

Downloading states (`DownloadingState` status) resumes if I restart the node process itself.

My question is
What is `AwaitingPeers` actually mean in the warp sync context. In which condition warp sync status become `AwaitingPeers`?

Comment: It is like you said, `AwaitingPeers` means that it is [Waiting for peers to connect](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/e155ab8aefbe5831cbd6100767bd111bbad32ee7/client/network/common/src/sync/warp.rs#L71-L75). How long does it get stuck? Does it resume after a while or you need to manually restart every time?

Comment: It's almost over 24hours. and yes, restarting process resumes Downloading state every time so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because state trie version migration hasn't been done yet.
state version needs to be `1`.
For more information
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/13921#issuecomment-1518812972
https://hackmd.io/@kizi/HyoSO3lf9

Answer (score 2):

This may be a bug, if `warp_sync_params` is set to `None` it will get stuck in `AwaitingPeers`:

```rust
(None, SyncMode::Warp, _) =>
    Some(WarpSyncProgress { phase: WarpSyncPhase::AwaitingPeers, total_bytes: 0 }),
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/53c58fbc3dc6060a2f611a8d7adfdeea655fe324/client/network/sync/src/lib.rs#L516-L517

You can see this will not happen if you have `warp_sync_params` configured. Cumulus has a good example:

```rust
let warp_sync_params = match parachain_config.network.sync_mode {
    SyncMode::Warp => {
        let target_block = warp_sync_get::<Block, RCInterface>(
            para_id,
            relay_chain_interface.clone(),
            spawn_handle.clone(),
        );
        Some(WarpSyncParams::WaitForTarget(target_block))
    },
    _ => None,
};
```

```rust
sc_service::build_network(sc_service::BuildNetworkParams {
    config: parachain_config,
    client,
    transaction_pool,
    spawn_handle,
    import_queue,
    block_announce_validator_builder: Some(Box::new(block_announce_validator_builder)),
    warp_sync_params,
})
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/574f425fa2b9c822a1417af705169ab3a1835e24/client/service/src/lib.rs#L344-L368

So make sure you have `warp_sync_params` configured.

Issue was opened here: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/13921

Comment: Actually, I'm using `cumulus_client_service::build_network`.

So, warp_sync_params should be configured inside the function you shared above.

https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/blob/574f425fa2b9c822a1417af705169ab3a1835e24/client/service/src/lib.rs#L344-L368

Comment: Thank you for opening Github issue, please let me comment there.